# How to commit in SQLite Android?

Tags: android, database, sql-update, android-sqlite, commit

I want to update my sqlite table in my app, but it is not working.
This is my code:

```
public boolean updateTable(Employee emp) {
    String idEmp = emp.getId();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Employee.COLUMN_ADDRESS,emp.getAddress());
        contentValues.put(Employee.COLUMN_CODE_CITY,emp.getCodeCity());
        contentValues.put(Employee.COLUMN_COMPANY_CODE,emp.getCompanyCode());
        long result = db.update(Employee.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] {idEmp});
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: _but not work._ What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I want to update table, but table was not updated...easy!

Comment: _easy!..._ You have to describe your issues/errors as exactly as possible... it is not that "easy" to understand "not work" in a technical way...

Comment: This is the normal method to update some table, but in this case (maybe) the update query is not committed

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine, other than a few issues that may confuse matters.

That is update will never return -1 it will return 0 (nothing updated) or a positive number (number of rows updated). As such false will never be returned.

The other issue is that your are trapping any exception and doing nothing. and potentially hiding useful information.

However I suggest that your issue is that your update is not actually updating (no matching id) but is returning true instead of the false so it's not the commit that is failing but simply that no update has been done.

Changing `if (result == -1) {` to **`if (result == 0) {`** would return a more indicative result.